# lxml tree.find is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I am having an issue with the command find and it is not working. However, in theory it should be working.

Let's say that I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"> 
<pxml name="es">
   things here
</pxml
```

I want to find the element pxml to add there an attribute. So I am using this code:

```
from lxml import etree as et
lang = 'de'
tree = et.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
txml_element = root.find('//pxml')
txml_element.attrib['language'] = lang
```

I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: cannout use absolute path on element
```

Also, if i don't do the tree.getroot and I use the find in the tree I always a None element. What do I am missing?

I don't understand why am I getting this message error. Also if use only root.find('pxml') it returns None.

However, using xpath I get a list of the elements, it works:

```
lang = 'de'
tree = et.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
txml_elements = root.xpath('//pxml')
for element in txml_elements:
    element.attrib['language'] = lang
    print(element.attrib)
#print (et.tostring(tree))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use dot:

```
root.find('.')
```

If you need only pxml element, check for tag

```
txml_element.tag
```

https://repl.it/IzNt/2

Comment: Thank you :) It works here. However, if I need to find an element that is in the middle of the tree I would have continuing the same problem, that I cannot use the find because it returns None or the error mentioned in the body of the question.